# PHP Symfony2 BLOB data display using TWIG

Tags: php, symfony

In my database, I have images in blob columns which I am retrieving these images and showing to the user via HTML.

Now, the problem is:

In PHP when I do

```
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```

I shows me image in browser, However, through TWIG or HTML, I am not able to show the image. passing the same `$image` 
like

```
return this->render("...twig",array($name -> $image));
```

But it does not work... `$name` is attribute in `img` tag in TWIG. Browser simply shows junk data for this field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must to pass variable like:

```
return this->render("...twig", array('image' => $name->$image));
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image data into base64 and display it with `img` tag. You can put the conversion logic inside a Twig extension and display it something like this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ imageData|base64 }}" alt="" />
```